# Minecraft Performance Problem

Tags: drivers, java, performance, minecraft

So, i switched from Windows 11 to Ubuntu yesterday and i have installed all the programs i had before.
Although Minecraft Java is running extremely bad on my new OS, any ideas why?
Before i switched my average framerate was on about 200 FPS, now the best my PC can do is 25 FPS.

---

HARDWARE

GPU: NVIDIA RTX 3050;

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 4500 6-Core Processor

RAM: 16 GB

---

Things i have tried to fix the issue:

- Update Java (To JDK 21)
- Allocate more RAM (no matter how much RAM i allocate, Minecraft never uses more than
  1GB, i have no idea why.)
- Install Drivers (All the drivers i can install mess up my screen resolution and only
  the preinstalled one has my monitors resolution, so that one did not work.
- Change my games version, ealier versions like 1.8.9 do have the same problem.
- Install Clients (Lunar client maxes out at around 30 FPS)
- Install Performance mods (Sodium, Optifine or Lithium do not affect my framerate)

So. Does any Person out there have any idea what i could do?
I have given up on trying.

Comment: What graphics card do you have?  The graphics card you have is important here.

Comment: Maybe you're using onboard graphics instead of your card? What's your `inxi` (system information: CPU, GPU, etc.) look like? What's your full command line?

Comment: I will add my hardware models to the post.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your graphics card driver is compatible with your Ubuntu version and Minecraft. Some users reported that using the nvidia-prime driver instead of bumblebee or primus improved their performance. You can also try to update your driver to the latest version available for your card

Remove Bumblebee by running:
`sudo apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`
Install nvidia-prime by running:
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime`
Reboot the system

Comment: Sadly i am having troubles installing the driver, is there a way to check if it successfully installed?
It said successful but after a reboot i can not see any changes.

Comment: Yeah you can ckeck it by typing `nvidia-smi`